# AWS without Amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, aws-amplify, mern

I'm working on a MERN web app (React, MongoDB, NodeJS). It's not a CRUD-like app because it's more oriented towards Graph-related data structures.

I'd like to migrate it to Cloud hosting. I've considered AWS as it's the most popular and during AWS Days learned about Amplify and thought it was great.

However, looking at several forums, it seems AWS Amplify is not yet a mature product. 
It allows to create basic web apps but if customization is needed(more complex DB queries, etc), you have to directly interact with Dynamo DB. Over time the web app becomes spaghetti code and you're not actually using Amplify anymore.

So does AWS provide a way to build web apps without using Amplify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try Elastic Beanstalk as mentioned [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_nodejs.html).

As Elastic Beanstalk provides load balancer as well so it would better solution for MERN and MEAN stack based application.

Comment: Meantime found this nice idea: Code a wrapper around your cache, data and message stores so you can switch technologies/providers.
Which I hope to achieve - Elastic Beanstalk looks interesting, I'll try it first.

https://lugassy.net/why-we-moved-from-amazon-web-services-to-google-cloud-platform-726c412fd667

Comment: AWS is much mature than Google cloud. Google cloud platform is growing. but AWS is already grown and much reliable for Production.